# Build Error with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, build, sdk

first of this is my first app, and first time using Android Studio, so I am hoping it's just a small thing I don't understand yet.

Here are my error messages;

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"ERROR","text":"No resource found that matches the given name (at \u0027icon\u0027 with value \u0027@mipmap/ic_launcher\u0027).","sourcePath":"C:\\Users\\Matt\\AndroidStudioProjects\\FirstApp\\app\\build\\intermediates\\manifests\\full\\debug\\AndroidManifest.xml","position":{"startLine":13,"startColumn":23,"startOffset":385,"endColumn":42,"endOffset":404},"original":""}


FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\Matt\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

This is the code on the Manifest xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.matt.firstapp" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

With the following error message on line 7; 
Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher' less... (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

I already have android 21.1.2 installed:

[image: android sdk manager, packages and versions]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would certainly be easier to answer if you could post the content of your AndroidManfiest.xml

Answer (score 2):

The Unicode escape notation `\u0027` stands for a quote character. Thus, from the error message, it looks like you have something similar to `'icon' = '@mipmap/ic_launcher'` somewhere in your AndroidManifest.xml, and I'm guessing it should be more like `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`.

Comment: this is the line; 

    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"


Cannot resolve symbol '@mipmap/ic_launcher' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Validates resource references inside Android XML files

Comment: yup. should refer '@drawable/'

Comment: @Matthew do you actually have, under `app/src/main/res`, a set of folders `mipmap-mdpi`, `mipmap-hdpi` etc...? At least one of them should have an `ic_launcher.png` file in it.